# Modify OpenERP 6.1 product form view in web client

Tags: formview, odoo, web-client

I'm trying to modify the product view of OpenERP 6.1 (web client) to include my own widget, allowing me to select a color using three sliders. This is a very simple requirement, some times we'll need to customize a specific web view to change the way OpenERP create its interface. Is it possible and how? I follow online docs ([OpenERP Web’s documentation](http://planet.domsense.com/docs/openerp-web/en/index.html)) but I don't realise how to perform this change...

[This is what I'll like to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYi9j.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the new 6.1 web client, but it sounds like you might want to [subclass Widget](http://planet.domsense.com/docs/openerp-web/en/addons.html#subclassing-widget) for your slider control. There isn't much detail in that documentation, so you'll probably have to look in the web client source code to see how the basic widgets are implemented.